# Why is DatabaseCleaner causing this RSpec controller test to fail?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, database-cleaner

I am attempting to setup DatabaseCleaner with RSpec to make sure that I can properly cleanup any test objects that I have created. If I don't use DatabaseCleaner, then the following test passes.

However, when I add the DatabaseCleaner code to my `spec_helper.rb` file, the test fails as outlined below.

```
include AuthHelper

describe BulkJobsController do

  describe 'GET /bulk_jobs/:id' do

    context 'with valid user' do
      before do
        login_as('someuser')
      end

      context 'and a job' do
        before do
          @job = create(:bulk_job_close_cases)

          puts "Test - Bulk Job Count: #{BulkJob.count}" # This is always 1

          get :show, id: @job.id, format: 'json'
        end

        it 'is valid' do
          response.status.should eq(200)
        end
      end
    end

  end

end
```

Here is the controller:

```
class BulkJobsController < ApiController

  def show
    puts "Controller - Bulk Job Count: #{BulkJob.count}" # This is 1 without DC and 0 with DC
    @job = BulkJob.find(params[:id])

    respond_with @job
  end

end
```

Here is the relevant portion of my `spec/spec_helper.rb` file:

```
####################
# Database Cleanup #
####################
require 'database_cleaner'
config.use_transactional_fixtures = false

config.after(:suite) do
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("DEALLOCATE ALL")
end

config.around(:each) do |example|
  DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
  DatabaseCleaner.start

  example.run

  DatabaseCleaner.clean
end
```

Oddly, removing the `DatabaseCleaner.clean` statement doesn't actually make the test pass either; however, removing the `DatabaseCleaner.start` code *does* make the test pass.

The test is failing because the controller can't find a BulkJob with the proper ID. If I print out the counts of the objects, inside the test the number of BulkJobs is 1, but inside the controller, it's 0. When the test passes, obviously, the number is 1 in both spots.

I haven't included Capybara or Selenium, so as I understand it, rspec should be using rack-test to run this example.

**Is there something wrong with my configuration/test? Is DatabaseCleaner cleaning too early?**

Here is the failing test:

```
Failures:

  1) BulkJobsController GET /bulk_jobs/:id with valid user and a job is valid
     Failure/Error: get :show, id: @job.id, format: 'json'
     ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound:
       Couldn't find BulkJob with id=39
     # ./app/controllers/bulk_jobs_controller.rb:6:in `show'
     # ./spec/controllers/bulk_jobs_spec.rb:33:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

and my Gemfile:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '~>3.2.12'
gem 'composite_primary_keys', '>=3.1.0'
gem 'sqlite3-ruby', :require => 'sqlite3'
gem 'pg'
gem 'activerecord-mysql2-adapter', '~> 0.0.3'
gem 'rake', '>=0.8.7'
gem 'dalli'
gem 'postmark-rails'
gem 'rb-readline'
gem 'statsmix'

gem 'daemons'
gem 'delayed_job_active_record'
gem 'whenever', :require => false
gem 'iron_worker'
gem 'statsmix'

gem 'exceptional'
#gem 'newrelic_rpm'

group :test do
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'shoulda-matchers'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
end
```